# forget widgets inside a PanedWindow in Tkinter

Tags: tkinter, ttk

since from what I understood in Tkinter the PanedWindow widget is such that what goes inside doesnt have to be packed/gridded, but added to the parent, e.g.

```
pwin = PanedWindow()
pwin.pack()    
top = Label(pwin, text="top pane")
pwin.add(top)    
bottom = Label(pwin, text="bottom pane")
pwin.add(bottom)
```

how can I have inside it (`pwin`) objects that I want to make appear/disappear, since I usually do this by `.pack()`/`.pack_forget()` ?

Comment: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/panedwindow.htm#Tkinter.PanedWindow.forget-method

Comment: Are you wanting to destroy a pane, keep the pane but make it temporarily invisible, or keep the pane visible but make everything inside it disappear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PanedWindow](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/panedwindow.htm) have a `forget`method accepting a widget as parameter.

In your example, you migh use `pwin.forget(bottom)`.